# Why is there a towel on my toilet seat?

Tags: singapore, toilets

I checked in to my hotel in Singapore and the toilet has a towel on its lid.
[image: Towel on the seat]

What is the objective of this towel? Is it supposed to be used a foot rug for when I am using the toilet?

Comment: It never occured to me, that bath mats might not be a known worldwide phenomenon. Nice question! :)

Comment: The toilet was cold, so it's keeping warm. It's like a shawl.

Comment: @Ian: Even knowing about bath mats, I wouldn't expect to find one on the toilet.

Comment: That is true. I am familiar with the concept of a bath rug, but I wouldn't be expecting it on top of my toilet.

Comment: Where's the rest of the toilet?

Comment: Go ask at reception in a fist-pounding-on-the-counter manner and demand an explanation in an outrage.

Comment: Is that the Pan Pacific by any chance?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No its Hotel Mi Bencoolen

Comment: @Sinstein Stab in the dark :D

Comment: @Harper: Though not particularly relevant to the question I assume the cistern will be behind the wall panels (assuming that is what you meant by "rest of the toilet").

Comment: @Chris Or it could just [not have one](https://home.howstuffworks.com/tankless-toilet.htm). Tankless toilets are relatively common for commercial buildings, which often have sufficient pressure in their water supplies to not need the tank.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It’s a bath mat - for use when stepping out of the shower, or indeed as you say, when using the toilet (tiled floors can be cold underfoot!)

Comment: In many hotels they leave them on the edge of the bathtub. However this is clearly impossible here, so it's the next best location. They don't put it with the rest of the towels so you don't get them confused. And they often don't leave them on the floor as the floor might still be wet when they leave.

Comment: I think equally a safety issue: to dry your feet coming out of the shower so you don't slip on the tile, fall, and sue the hotel.

Comment: And in this position it serves an additional purpose to indicate the toilet has not been used since the room was cleaned.

Comment: You can sort of tell it's the bath mat because of the rectangle decoration cut into it that a normal towel wouldn't have.

Comment: As well as the rectangle decoration it's quite different from a towel- it's less fluffy and designed not to slip on the floor.

Comment: "*However this is clearly impossible here*".  Why?

Comment: @RonJohn Because there (likely) is no bathtub. That glass on the right looks like a shower door.

Comment: @davidbak: I saw a lot of them which also had small footsteps on them to make it obvious

Comment: In the hotels I've stayed in, that embossed rectangle pattern appears on the bath mat (as opposed to the towels which have a different pattern, or none.)

Answer (score 12):

They are the thick ones, I usually put these on the floor, wipe the floor with them (using my foot) in case it got wet.

I could be using them wrong all these years, but hey! I love using them that way.

Comment: I love the idea of turning to a Neanderthal for advice on how to use hotels. :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby we managed in caves, we can manage in hotels..

Comment: Cave manager to hotel manager, not bad

Comment: @npst: [obligatory job interview video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b56eAUCTLok)

Comment: Have you considered a cave hotel, perhaps in Cappadocia?

Comment: “I don't know, but“